# mongoDb error getting while querying the DB "cannot add session into the cache"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongo server `4.0.2` and sometimes getting the below error while trying to query the mongoDb database using `mongoose` `"^5.2.5"`

here the error object

```
"err": {
    "message": "cannot add session into the cache",
    "name": "MongoError",
    "stack": "MongoError: cannot add session into the cache\n    at queryCallback (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:248:25)\n    at /var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:531:18\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)",
    "code": 261
},
```

here is the code for DB connection

```
const dbClient = require('./dbConnection');
let connectionPromise = dbClient(null, (error) => { console.log(error); });
connectionPromise.then(function() {
    //....
    //....
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

here the code for `dbConnection.js` [gist](https://gist.github.com/abuzarhamza/922a48612bb2e4d56c90533d02927f42)

Is there any way, I can handle this error in my node js script or altogether avoid such error from `mongoDb` side?

Comment: Which mongoose version ? and what's the code that generated the error ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar: added the code and other version details.

Comment: This issue may be related to the one recently added on Mongo bug tracker : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-39044